# How to do unit test on database connection function?

Tags: flask, tdd

I have a Flask app that use this function to connect to DB server:

```
@contextmanager
def db_connection(name):
    server = os.environ.get(name + '_SERVER')
    database = os.environ.get(name + '_DATABASE')
    username = os.environ.get(name + '_USERNAME')
    password = os.environ.get(name + '_PASSWORD')
    info = dict(server=server, database=database, user=username, password=password, timeout=timeout)
    conn = pymssql.connect(**info)
    conn.autocommit(True)

    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

How to construct test cases? I assume for unit test case, I would just mock the `pymssql.connect`. For integration test, I need use a fixture to set up a test database, is it correct? Is there any examples?

What if the connection function has logging, `app.logger.info("...")`, the test complains about not setup app context properly. How to resolve it?

Comment: I wouldn't unit test that (and by definition if you already have the implementation this isn't [tag:tdd]). Also passing all of the arguments into a `dict` then unpacking them seems totally pointless.

Comment: agree. that pack and unpacking isn't necessary.

Comment: I think a test case is still needed, since it serves  a contract to prevent others breaking it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as below. test ensure the conn is establish and released without connecting to a real db.

```
def test_db_connection(test_client):
    connection_mock = MagicMock()
    connection_mock.autocommit.return_value = None

    name = "DC1"
    server = os.environ.get(name + '_SERVER')
    database = os.environ.get(name + '_DATABASE')
    username = os.environ.get(name + '_USERNAME')
    password = os.environ.get(name + '_PASSWORD')
    timeout = int(os.environ.get(name + 'TIMEOUT_DB', 60))

    with patch('pymssql.connect', return_value=connection_mock) as connect_mock:
        with db_connection(name) as conn:
            connect_mock.assert_called_once_with(server=server,
                                                 database=database,
                                                 user=username,
                                                 password=password,
                                                 timeout=timeout)

            connection_mock.autocommit.assert_called_once_with(True)

        assert connection_mock.close.called
```

test fixture is

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    # Set the Testing configuration prior to creating the Flask application
    os.environ['CONFIG_TYPE'] = 'config.TestingConfig'
    flask_app = create_app()

    # Create a test client using the Flask application configured for testing
    with flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
        # Establish an application context
        with flask_app.app_context():
            yield testing_client  # this is where the testing happens!
```